# Is it possible to have an enum with a value containing a slash?

Tags: c#, .net

I have an enum, with two values. However, the second value contains a slash (the value is application/xml). This causes a number of syntax values to show up. Is it not possible to have an enum with a member like this?

And if this is the case, what is the solution?

Thanks

Comment: The solution is normally to change the name of the enum member to a valid .NET identifier, like `ApplicationXml`. Is there something preventing you from doing that?

Comment: Not really. It's just that I will be using this value in a http request so I'd need to put the / back in, but that's very easy to do with some string parsing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Enum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032.aspx) values can only be integral types (byte, sbyte, short, ushort, int, uint, long, or ulong). Enum names can only be [valid .NET identifiers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664670%28VS.71%29.aspx) => no `/` possible. So the solution to whatever you are trying to do (which you haven't explained in your question) would be not to use enums. One possible alternative is to use a [`Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx). But once again without knowing your exact scenario and what you are trying to achieve it is difficult to propose a precise answer.

Answer (score 2):

You could just use a helper class and declare those values as const strings:

```
public static class MimeTypes
{
    public const string ApplicationXml = "application/xml";
    public const string AsfVideo = "video/wmv";
}

...
string xmlMime = MimeTypes.ApplicationXml;
```

Answer (score 1):

No. You're not giving the enum its *values*, you're providing *identifiers* for those values. The identifiers have to follow the same rules as identifiers anywhere else, i.e. no slashes.

Comment: This answer clicked with me.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Enum values must be integral types, but if you want to map strings to strings, you can use `Dictionary<string, string>`. See [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx).

Answer (score -1):

If it's a string place a @ symbol infront of the quotes.  That should work.

`@"application/xml"`

Comment: It works with quotes? Interesting. *[Quick Check]* No, it doesn't. That's a verbatim string...

Comment: the OP was asking about `enum`s, not about `string`s. Unlike other languages (e.g. F# being one of them), C# doesn't allow identifiers to contain arbitrary characters, nor can you "escape" identifiers to get around that limitation.

Comment: In addition to @stakx's point, `@` would only be helpful if we were talking about a *back* slash, i.e. `application\xml`.